# Display of the missed messages from the publisher with a new subscriber connection (MQTT / Mosquitto)

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

Publusher sends a message `-m "hello"` to the topic `-t hello` using the command `mosquitto_pub -h 172.17.*.* -t hello -m "hello" -d`. The subscriber sees the message `-m "hello"` only if the connection to the topic `-t hello` is active. However, if the subscriber is not subscribed to the `-t hello` topic and the publisher still sends messages on the `-t hello` topic, then when you try to subscribe to this topic `mosquitto_sub -h 172.17. *. * -t hello` subscriber does not receive sent messages from publisher.

After reading the documentation, breaking a couple of brokers, I achieved only the fact that you can see the last message if you put the flag on the publisher `-r` like this - `-mosquitto_pub -h 172.17. *. * -r -t hello -m "hello"`. I configured `mosquitto.conf`, because I thought that the main changes, an example of the current problem, can only be achieved through it.

**How can I solve such a problem, I would like to see all missed messages from publisher when i resubscribe to the topic?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [QOS](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/) (Quality of Service) values for the messages. By default QOS is set to 0 which is basically fire and forget, QOS 1 is ensure delivery (but could mean delivered more than once). QOS 2 is ensured delivery only once.

It's needs pointing out that QOS is between 1 client and the broker, so this can be between the publisher and the broker, or the broker and a subscriber independently. (e.g. you can publish at QOS 0 and then subscribe to the topic at QOS 2).

For message queuing for offline clients, the client needs to have been subscribed at QOS 1 or QOS 2 and when it reconnects it needs to have it's cleanSession flag set to `false` and use the same client id.

MQTT brokers will not queue messages for clients that have never connected before.

With [mosquitto_sub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) and [mosquitto_pub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html) you can set the QOS level with `-q` option and you can set the client id with the `-i` option. To set the clean session flag to false for mosquitto_sub you should use the `-c` option

Comment: hardillb, thanks a lot, although i haven't tried these methods yet. And one question for u - I need to configure mosquitto.conf for this problem or its just solution on the level of  mosquitto_sub and  mosquitto_pub?

Comment: It depends, if you want queued messages to survive a broker restart then you need to make sure the mosquitto has persistence enabled

Comment: ok, i'll try it soon and give u feedback along with the "finally_right_answer" mark